# What is the difference between 很, 十分 and 非常?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between 很, 十分 and 非常? Or do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. 很 = very

   - **很** 謝謝 你 = Thank you very much
   - 你 **很** 厲害 = You are very good.
2. 非常 = 十分 = extremely

   - **十分/非常** 謝謝 你
   - 你 **十分/非常** 厲害
3. Word by word:

   - 非-常 = extra-ordinary, ab-normal
   - 十分 = 100 percent

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that 很 is more often than not used to couple nouns and adjectives. It then only means "is" rather then "very".

- 他很高 / he is tall
- 他非常高 / he is very tall
- 他十分高 / he is extremely tall
- 他高极了 / he is extremely tall (modifier after adjective)

Although you could simply say 他高, it is more common to use 很 as copula.

Comment: should be “他高极了 ”. But this expression is still unusual for me. “高极了” usually used with more complex subjects like "这座房子“(this house) or without subject at all ("- 这山有多高？ -高极了！").